# How to fetch a specific key from a dictionary having multiple arrays and store into string placed in table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary

Here are the labels placed in the tableView Cells with name a, b, c, d

```
//Want to store passenger_no here
    cell.a.text; 
//Want to store depart_city here
    cell.b.text; 
//Want to store name here
cell.d.text;
```

Here am fetch the JSON data and storing into array of name array and storing that array into dictionary named as dict

```
NSArray *array = [_json valueForKey:@"result"];
NSDictionary *dict = array[indexPath.row];
```

The JSON looks like this :

```
{ "result": [
        { "passenger_no": 4,
          "destination_detail": [
                { "depart_city": "Indira Gandhi International"}],
          "aircraft_info": [{ "name": "CEAT 450"}]
}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you can assign fetched value to text label in your cell like this:

```
NSArray *array = [_json valueForKey:@"result"];
NSDictionary *dict = array[indexPath.row];

//Want to store passenger_no here
cell.a.text = [dict valueForKey:@"passenger_no"];

//Want to store depart_city here
NSArray *destinationDetails = [dict valueForKey:@"destination_detail"];
NSDictionary *departcityInfo = destinationDetails.firstObject;
cell.b.text = [departcityInfo valueForKey:@"depart_city]"

//Want to store name here
NSArray *aircraftInfoList = [dict valueForKey:@"aircraft_info"];
NSDictionary *aircraftInfo = aircraftInfoList.firstObject;
cell.d.text = [aircraftInfo valueForKey:@"name"];
```

*PS.* In **Modern Objective-C Syntax**, you can access value of `NSDictionary` by `dict[@""passenger_no"]` instead of `[dict valueForKey:@"passenger_no"]`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

So in `cellforrowatindexpath` your code will be like below

```
NSDictionary *dict = array[indexPath.row];
    NSArray *destinationdetailarray = [dict valueForKey:@"destination_detail"];
    NSString *departcity = [[destinationdetailarray firstObject]valueForKey:@"depart_city"];
    NSString *passengerno = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"passenger_no"]];
    NSArray *aircraftinfo = [dict valueForKey:@"aircraft_info"];
    NSString *name = [[aircraftinfo firstObject]valueForKey:@"name"];
```